# error 500 in ajax call when call to the server, but in localhost works

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a js when i do a ajax call to one server. When i call to this service using localhost, works. But when i call to this service using the server where i upload it, its ERROR 500. The call return a json.

```
 $.ajax({
            url: "https://www.example.com/example",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                'data': xml,
                'message': message,
                'customer_id': customer_id,
                'subscr_id': subscr_id
            },
            type: 'POST',
            success: function (devol) {


            },
            error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert("no ha entrado");
            }
        });
```

Comment: To clarify, when in your localhost, the url your ajax is using is also from localhost? And once on the server, the url your ajax is using is also from the same domain of the server?

Comment: When in my localhost, the URL in my Ajax is using from localhost and works. But When the service is in the server and the URL in my Ajax is from the server, its error 500

Comment: Can you show us the error message maybe?

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your code below:

```
var model = {
            'data': xml,
            'message': message,
            'customer_id': customer_id,
            'subscr_id': subscr_id
        };
$.ajax({
        url: "https://www.example.com/example",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(model),
        //headers: { 'authorization': `Bearer ${token}` },
        async: false,
        processData: false,
        contentType: "application/json",
        error: function (err) {
        },
        success: function (data) {  
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be because of CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing)... Usually, you cannot make calls to other domains from the browser unless the other domain you are making calls allows CORS to all sites or specific sites.

[enter link description here](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/)